# How to change profile picture using Mesibo?

Tags: android, ios, livechat

I'm using Mesibo to create an app chat, everything works fine until I want to change profile picture of contact. I used to find in demo app and try to set `mesiboUserProfile.picturePath = "online picture url"` after add `name` and `phone` in `addContact` method but nothing happen. Profile picture still use default image. Did I miss something? Really need your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: is this, android or ios?

Comment: I get this issue in both of android and ios @Ivan

Comment: picturePath should be the local path. If you post code, I can look into for  you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the image manually from android using retrofit or something and then save it to `/Mesibo/Profiles` folder in internal storage of your app. This is where the profile pictures are stored by mesibo. Mesibo won't fetch any image url rather it will load from `your_app_package/Mesibo/Profiles` folder.